# Optimizing .txt files creation speed

Tags: c++, file, optimization, fstream, ofstream

I've written the following simple testing code, that creates 10 000 empty .txt files in a subdirectory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

void CreateFiles()
{
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= 10000) {
        int filename = i;
        std::string string_i = std::to_string(i);
        std::string file_dir = ".\\results\\"+string_i+".txt";
        std::ofstream outfile(file_dir);
        i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    clock_t tStart1 = clock();
    CreateFiles();
    printf("\nHow long it took to make files: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine. All 10 000 .txt files are created within `~3.55` seconds. (using my PC)

**Question 1:** Ignoring the conversion from `int` to `std::string` etc., is there anything that I could optimize here for the program to create the files faster? I specifically mean the `std::ofstream outfile` usage - perhaps using something else would be relevantly faster?

Regardless, `~3,55` seconds is satisfying compared to the following:

I have modified the function so right now it would also fill the .txt files with some random `i` integer data and some constant text:

```
void CreateFiles()
{
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= 10000) {
        int filename = i;
        std::string string_i = std::to_string(i);
        std::string file_dir = ".\\results\\"+string_i+".txt";
        std::ofstream outfile(file_dir);

        // Here is the part where I am filling the .txt with some data
        outfile << i << " some " << i << " constant " << i << " text " << i << " . . . " 
        << i << " --more text-- " << i << " --even more-- " << i;
        i++;
    }
}
```

And now everything (creating the .txt files and filling it with short data) executes within... `~37` seconds. That's a huge difference. And that's only 10 000 files.

**Question 2:** Is there anything I can optimize here? Perhaps there exist some alternative that would fill the .txt files quicker. Or perhaps I have forgotten about something very obvious that slows down the entire process?

Or, perhaps I am exaggerating a little bit and `~37` seconds seems normal and optimized?

Thanks for sharing your insights!

Comment: Nothing new, io streams are not really fast in C++. You should try the C counterpart if your only focus is performance. Give [{fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) a look too, AFAIK it's able to work with streams directly.

Comment: Yeah, writing to files is expensive, esp. when you need high throughput. Not surprising the order of magnitude difference when writing something to the files.

Comment: Also can you try just outputting `outfile << 'a'`? If you get crazy higher numbers than without writing anything, I would suspect filesystem performance to be a culprit.

Comment: My guess is this is going as fast as the disk can handle. It is likely the disk alone that is slowing this down. In the first test it only needs to change the directory in one place on the disk. In the second one it has to visit each file on the disk to put information there.

Comment: *is there anything that I could optimize here for the program to create the files faster?* -- Be careful trying to optimize any code that has to do with file writing.  What may be optimal for your hardware may have no effect or worse, make things slower when run on different hardware.

Comment: @Asu `outfile << 'a';` generates `10000` .txt files in `4.70` seconds.

Comment: Try writing through unformatted input functions, such as 'std::ostream::write` and measure their performance (make sure to write the same amount of bytes). If it is significantly faster, your culprit is formatting, if it is the same, it is platform.

Comment: ``ostream::write`` gave even worse results D: +- 10%

Comment: Try writing to a RAMdrive to see if mechanical disk performance is limiting you.

Comment: Which system are using? If you happen to use MSVC++ you are using an implementation which tried to prove that IOStreams are slow. Of course, it didn't really prove what it set out to prove but rather that one implementation can be made slow. For this particular implementation using `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` as the first thing in `main()` had a rather large effect on performance when I tried it (which is, however, ~20 years ago).

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997131/stdfstream-buffering-vs-manual-buffering-why-10x-gain-with-manual-buffering

Comment: Having thousands of files in one directory makes for slow lookups there as well.

Comment: Win10 x64, Code::Blocks, G++ with C++14 flag enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The speed of creation of file is hardware dependent, faster the drive faster you can create the files.

This is evident from the fact that **I ran your code on an ARM processor** (Snapdragon 636, on a Mobile phone using termux), now mobile phones have flash memory that are very fast when it comes to I/O. So **it ran under 3 seconds most of the time and some time 5 second**. This variation is expected as drive has to handle multi process read writes. **You reported that it took 47 seconds for your hardware.** **Hence you can safely conclude that I/O speed is significantly dependent on Hardware.**

---

None the less I thought to do some optimization to your code and I used 2 different approaches.

- Using a C counterpart for I/O
- Using C++ but writing in a chunk in one go.

I ran the simulation on my phone. I ran it 50 times and here are the results.

- C was fastest taking 2.73928 second on average to write your word on 10000 text files, using fprintf
- C++ writing with the complete line at one go took 2.7899 seconds. I used sprintf to get the complete line into a char[] then wrote using << operator on ofstream.
- C++ Normal (Your Code) took 2.8752 seconds

This behaviour is expected, writing in chunks is fasters. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41210655/7309666) answer as to why. C was fastest no doubt.

You may note here that The difference is not that significant but if you are on a hardware with slow I/O, this becomes significant.

---

Here is the code I used for simulation. You can test it yourself but make sure to replace `std::system` argument with your own commands (different for windows).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

void CreateFiles()
{
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= 10000) {
       // int filename = i;
        std::string string_i = std::to_string(i);
        std::string file_dir = "./results/"+string_i+".txt";
        std::ofstream outfile(file_dir);

        // Here is the part where I am filling the .txt with some data
        outfile << i << " some " << i << " constant " << i << " text " << i << " . . . " 
        << i << " --more text-- " << i << " --even more-- " << i;
        i++;
    }
}

void CreateFilesOneGo(){
    int i = 1;
    while(i<=10000){
        std::string string_i = std::to_string(i);
        std::string file_dir = "./results3/" + string_i + ".txt";
        char buffer[256];
        sprintf(buffer,"%d some %d constant %d text %d . . . %d --more text-- %d --even more-- %d",i,i,i,i,i,i,i);
        std::ofstream outfile(file_dir);
        outfile << buffer;
        i++;
    }
}
        
void CreateFilesFast(){
    int i = 1;
    while(i<=10000){
    // int filename = i;
    std::string string_i = std::to_string(i);
    std::string file_dir = "./results2/"+string_i+".txt";
    FILE *f = fopen(file_dir.c_str(), "w");
    fprintf(f,"%d some %d constant %d text %d . . . %d --more text-- %d --even more-- %d",i,i,i,i,i,i,i);
    fclose(f);
    i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    double normal = 0, one_go = 0, c = 0;
    for (int u=0;u<50;u++){
        std::system("mkdir results results2 results3");
        
        clock_t tStart1 = clock();
        CreateFiles();
        //printf("\nNormal : How long it took to make files: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        normal+=(double)(clock() - tStart1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
       
        tStart1 = clock();
        CreateFilesFast();
        //printf("\nIn C : How long it took to make files: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        c+=(double)(clock() - tStart1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        
        tStart1 = clock();
        CreateFilesOneGo();
        //printf("\nOne Go : How long it took to make files: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        one_go+=(double)(clock() - tStart1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        
        std::system("rm -rf results results2 results3");
        std::cout<<"Completed "<<u+1<<"\n";
    }
    
    std::cout<<"C on average took : "<<c/50<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"Normal on average took : "<<normal/50<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"One Go C++ took : "<<one_go/50<<"\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

Also I used clang-7.0 as the compiler.

If you have any other approach let me know, I will test that too. If you find a mistake do let me know, I will correct it as soon as possible.

Comment: Note this is also compiler dependent, Linux/gcc provides a default `IO_BUFSIZ` (I believe renamed `LIO_BUFSIZE` currently) of `8192` bytes while Windows VS provide only `512`. So "increasing" to a fixed `4096` as indicated in the linked answer would actually be cutting the default I/O buffer size in half on Linux. (well done on the testing and reporting)